# How to fix content background sharing within Linkedin

Tags: html, wordpress

When my client wants to share this page on his Linkedin:
https://www.mysimilasan.com/distributeur-worden/

The background of the page is shown on Linkedin. I set all the right variables they have on there support page:
"Improve content sharing with Open Graph"
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

I waited 1,5 month because I thought it was a linkedin cache problem. But now the background image is still showing when trying to share this page.

it should share this image right:?

Anybody have ideas what I have done wrong here?
Or is this a Linkedin bug?

Comment: Place the image used for Open Graph meta tag somewhere on the page.

Comment: @zipkundan Thanks for your response, I added the same image I used for the Open Graph meta tag. But it still uses the background image of the page. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`og:` tags are the right way to go, but they are *not the only way to go.*  After all, looking at your page, I see, in fact, that you are also using oEmbed.  Just look at this URL on your site:

https://www.mysimilasan.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysimilasan.com%2Fdistributeur-worden%2F

The above link is used on your page, because your HTML indicates it, as so...

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="https://www.mysimilasan.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysimilasan.com%2Fdistributeur-worden%2F" />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="https://www.mysimilasan.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysimilasan.com%2Fdistributeur-worden%2F&#038;format=xml" />
```

And then looking at your oEmbed file itself, I see...

```
{
    ...
    thumbnail_url: "https://www.mysimilasan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/swiss-bg-2.jpg",
    thumbnail_width: 600,
    thumbnail_height: 362
}
```

***Hey, that's the image that's showing up incorrectly!***  That's where it's coming from!  I bet, if you change your oEmbed file, you'll make this work instantly!  (or, disable oEmbed, but let's go with the elegant solution)

To verify, I put your URL into the [LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fwww.mysimilasan.com%2Fdistributeur-worden%2F), and it gave a list of all possible files available for an icon, and *why it chose that image*.  Take a look!